# How can I store data from entity type selectbox (Symfony)?

Tags: symfony, controller, doctrine, entity, formbuilder

I have a select box created with formbuilder:

```
<select id="form_type" name="form[type]" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <option value="1">text</option>
  <option value="2">hidden</option>
  <option value="3">password</option>
  <option value="4" selected="selected">icon</option>
  <option value="5">select</option>
</select>
```

This is how it is created in my controller:

```
$formBuilder->add('type', EntityType::class, array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control select2'), 'label' => 'Type',
            'class' => FieldTypes::class,
            'choice_label' => function ($fieldTypes) {
              return $fieldTypes->getName();
              }
            ));

$formBuilder->add('cancel', ButtonType::class, array('label' => 'cancel','attr' => array('class' => 'cancel form-btn btn btn-default pull-right close_sidebar')))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save','attr' => array('id' => 'submit-my-beautiful-form','class' => 'form-btn btn btn-info pull-right','style' => 'margin-right:5px')));
        $form = $formBuilder->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
```

But when I want to save a selection I get the error message:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Fields::setType() must be an instance
>   of App\Entity\FieldTypes or null, string given, called in
>   /Users/work/project/src/Controller/PagesController.php on line 242

In my entity:

```
 public function setType(?FieldTypes $type): self
  {
    $this->type = $type;
    return $this;
  }
```

This is how it it stored:

```
$entity = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($EntityName)->find($data['form[id]']);
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $func = 'set'.$field['fieldName'];
   $args = $data['form['.$field['fieldName'].']'];
   $entity->$func($args);
}
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method `$form->handleRequest($request)`. It will populate your form using its configuration (it will instanciate a `FieldType` using the posted id).

Here, you add manually the "raw" value of your select, which is string containing the id of your `FieldType`.

edit : see the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions)

Comment: I have this already `  $form->handleRequest($request);` just did not post it here, must be another issue (I will update my question

Comment: I assumed you used a Form Class and create it with the `$this->createForm(Form::class, $type)` method, sorry. In that case, the $type variable is automatically filled with the Form posted value folowing the form configuration. That's the most proper way to use Form you should take a look at this ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, its little bit diffucult to understand but
if $field is as a string.

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
$obj = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($fieldEntity)->find(field);      
$entiy->setType($obj);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not sure, what `field` is, is it the related column name? This is how the entities are related: `/**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FieldTypes")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $type;`

Comment: It tested your code like this: `$fieldEntity = new FieldTypes();

                  $obj = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository($fieldEntity)->find(id);
                  $entiy->setType($obj);`

Comment: The error is now: `Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty`

Answer (score 0):

Try after form submit block

```
$entity->setType($form->get('type'));
```

$form->get('type') will return as a FieldTypes class.

also if you use $field instead of $field['fieldName'],
will object return.
for example,

```
$func = 'set'.$field;
```

Comment: `$func = 'set'.$field;` gives me the error `Notice: Array to string conversion`